Help with the Firefox snap icon
I wanted to make Firefox snap use the icons in my theme. I followed an older forum post that suggested copying the desktop file for /var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/firefox_firefox.desktop to ~/.local/share/applications. That does work in the menus.

However the icon is not reflected in the task bar/panel.

So far this only applies to the Firefox snap and the Thunderbird snap. For the VSCode snap, it uses the theme icon everywhere.
Is there a way to fix this?

I found a fix this by editing the Exec line in the desktop file in ~/.local/share/applications/firefox_firefox.desktop
Exec=env BAMF_DESKTOP_FILE_HINT=/home/user/.local/share/applications/firefox_firefox.desktop /snap/bin/firefox

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

on my pc running Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS in order to get the icon back:
delete the file: ~/.local/share/applications/firefox_firefox.desktop
logout(no reboot) and login again, the icon is back
